# Slide toggeling not working properly

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing MVC application with Razor syntax.
I am trying to Slidetoggle the Div, means when I click one Div other div should be expanded.
Its work fine after loading, but why its already expanded when page loads ? 
but in my application its already expanded/toggled.

How to solve this ?

```
 @model  IEnumerable<CRMEntities.Comment>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head runat="server">

    <title></title>


     <!DOCTYPE html>

    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function clearText() 

    {
         document.getElementById('Comment').value = "";

    }

</script>


<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".ShowComments").click(function () {

            $(".ParentBlock").slideToggle("slow");

        });

    });

</script>





<style type="text/css"> 

div.ParentBlock
{
position:relative;

}

div.ShowComments
{
   position:relative;

}

</style>



</head>
<body>

@{

    <p class="ShowComments">Show Comments</p>


    <div class="ParentBlock">



    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div id="OwnerName">

         <span class="EmpName"> @Html.ActionLink(item.Owner.FullName, "Details", "EMployee", new { id = item.OwnerId }, new { @style = "color:#1A6690;" })</span>

           @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.CommentDateTime)

        </div>

        <div id="CommentTextBlock">
           @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.CommentText)
        </div>
        <br />


    }



    </div>


   @Html.TextArea("Comment", "", 5, 80, "asdsd")


    <input type="button" value="Add Comment"/>                         
    <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clearText()"/>                    

}


</body>
</html>
```

The summary of the problem is, Div gets toggled before calling Jscript.
How to avoid it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the divs that should be hidden to hidden with css. this way it will be closed and slide open when you toggle it.